# Click on table row to navigate to other page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, onclick

I have read some articles on how to navigate to other pages by clicking a row or a div element. The most articles are over one year old so I was wondering if there was a more efficient way.

I dislike using Jquery, so the only option I found:

- adding a Onclick event in html --> I don't like

Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This may sound insane, but a `<tr>` isn't really rendered by a browser so it isn't "clickable" from within HTML. If you wanted the `<tr>` to be clickable, I can come up with two options.

1. Use Javascript/jQuery to catch the click event on the `<tr>` but you came up with this example already and it seems like you don't like this option.
2. In each `<td>` create a `<a href="#">` surrounding all your text, and then use CSS to make the `<a>` tag a block level element which would make the entire table cell clickable.

Comment: I guess the second option u just gave me will not be valid for the html validator... I like to avoid javascript / jquery because ppl can turn this off, which means they can't navigate my site. The only option i see at this point is that I place a <span> in my last column so they can click a 'button' there to change the users data for example...

Comment: Why wouldn't it be HTML valid? `<tr><td><a href="#">text here</a></td></tr>` is valid HTML.

Comment: oh misread your message, sorry. Thought you wrote to place a <a> element like : <a><tr><td>....</td></tr></a>. Still this seems wrong to fix it like that :) thx for the respons btw